# Mongoose Cascading 'remove' middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm learning MongoDB with Mongoose and I'm facing a little problem in order to clean my collections on removing document.

I've got 3 collections that are associated. Users, Blogposts and Comments.

On User model and Blogpost Model I've set a pre-remove function like this

**User Model**

```
UserSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
const Blogposts = mongoose.model('blogpost');
const Comments = mongoose.model('comment');

console.log('pre-remove user');

Promise.all([
    Blogposts.remove({_id: { $in: this.blogposts }}),
    Comments.remove({user: this._id})
]).then(next());
});
```

**Blog post Model**

```
BlogPostSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
const Comments = moongoose.model('comment');

console.log('pre-remove blogpost');

Comments.remove({_id: { $in: this.comments}})
    .then(next());
});
```

When I remove a user, it removes the blogposts and comments associated to the user but it seems that the pre-remove function on blog post model isn't called at all.

Any idea to remove all the comments from the blogposts removed in cascade ?

Comment: *If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(), not when you call MyModel.remove().* -- [source](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: You would have to find all the posts by the user and fire `remove()` on each one in order to call the hooks. This is one of the gotchas of mongoose.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. I use remove on a user instance so le hook is called for  the user and the blogposts are remove by the model instance so it isn't called !

Thanks for the clarification guys